# The Total Graph is similar to a line graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, open-problems, graph-colorings

Consider the [total graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalGraph.html) of a regular graph. From the structure, it seems that it has a similar structure to the line graph ( two different sub-cliques joining at a single point) except that, in addition, there is an edge between two different sub-cliques. Note that the sub-cliques in the total graph are the just the sub-cliques which are present in the line graph of the graph with a vertex added to each sub-clique make it adjacent to all the vertices of a particular sub-clique, thereby increasing the order of the sub-cliques by one. This means that the clique number of the total graph of a graph is one more than the clique number of the line graph of the same graph.

This leads me to infer that the total graph of a graph has similar chromatic properties as a line graph of a graph. Specifically, I expect the total graph of a graph to satisfy a similar bound to Vizing's theorem for line graphs. Will this be true? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "similar". It's known that $χ(T) ≤ Δ(G) + 10^{26}$, where $T$ is the total graph of $G$. As the graph $C_4$ have $Δ=2$ and $χ(T)=4$, it follows that the constant term is at least $2$. The [Total coloring conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_coloring) states that this is exactly the case, i.e. $χ(T) ≤ Δ(G) + 2$.

Comment: yes, that is what I am pointing at. So is there a way to prove the total coloring conjecture using the structure of line graphs?

Comment: Well, the problem is open.